# Product Rule and Distributions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, distribution-theory

Suppose $f,g$ are smooth functions and $\phi$ is a test function.
the product rule for distributions has that:
$$[fg]'\{\phi\}=[fg]\{-\phi'\}=[f'g]\{\phi\}+[fg']\{\phi\} $$
I would like to multiply the derivative $[fg]'\{\phi\}$ by $\frac{1}{g(x)}$. Concretely, suppose everything is defined on $(0,\infty)$ and $g(x)=e^{-x}$. Is is correct that:
$$[fg]'\{\phi\}=\int_0^\infty [f(x)'e^{-x}\phi(x) - f(x)e^{-x}\phi(x)]dx$$
and so
$$\frac{1}{g(x)}([fg]'\{\phi\})=\int_0^\infty [f(x)'\phi(x) - f(x)\phi(x)]dx$$

Comment: Is anyone of $f, g, \phi$ supported only on $(0,\infty)$?

Comment: Is it perhaps that you mean with "suppose everything is defined on $(0,\infty)$"?

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $f,g,\phi$ are supported on $(0,\infty).$ Then,
$$
[fg]′\{ϕ\}
= -[fg]\{ϕ′\}
= -\int_0^\infty f(x)\,g(x)\,\phi'(x)\,dx
= \int_0^\infty (fg)'(x)\,\phi(x)\,dx
.
$$
With $g(x)=e^{-x}$ this becomes
$$
\int_0^\infty (fe^{-\bullet})'(x)\,\phi(x)\,dx
= \int_0^\infty (f'e^{-\bullet}-fe^{-\bullet})(x)\,\phi(x)\,dx
= \int_0^\infty (f'(x)e^{-x}-f(x)e^{-x})\,\phi(x)\,dx
.
$$

Comment: thanks. a few followups: what does the notation above the exponentials on the bottom left/middle mean? and finally, if i wish to take the final term and multiply by $e^x$ we end with the final expression in the original question? thanks again!

Comment: You mean the bullet, $e^{-\bullet}$? The bullet is a placeholder for where the argument goes, i.e. $e^{-\bullet}(x) = e^{-x}.$